# integrating jquery ui Autocomplete with a select box loaded from a server

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, jquery-ui

I have a page that loads a `<select>` box from a database

### **HTML**

```
                <form>                      
                        <?php
                            echo get_list_of_clients_in_option_tag();
                        ?>

                </form>
```

### **PHP**

```
function get_list_of_clients_in_option_tag(){
    $doinmysql = "SELECT id, full_name, company FROM clients";

    $clients = mysql_query($doinmysql) 
    or die("ERROR WHILE TRYING TO GET LIST OF CLIENTS general_functions.php ON get_list_of_clients. \n\r sql query: $doinmysql");

    $return = "<select name='clientID' id='client' class='saveData blue'>";
    while($this_row = mysql_fetch_array($clients)){
        $return .= "<option value='".$this_row['id']."'>";
        $return .=  $this_row['full_name']." - ".$this_row['company'];
        $return .= "</option>";
    }
    $return .= "</select>";
    return $return;
}
```

Instead of the `<select>` box I'd rather have an `<input type="text">` box that you can use as a search bar that would auto-complete the clients names in case there are too many clients for manually searching the client's name in the list.
I'd prefer using JQuery UI's "Autocomplete" widget but to use it you need to put in the source for the options yourslef-
for example:

### HTML

```
<input type="text" id="list_of_clients_search" />
```

### JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
     $(function() {
        var availableTutorials  =  [
           " ActionScript",
           " Boostrap",
           " C",
           " C++",
        ];
        $( "#list_of_clients_search" ).autocomplete({
           source: availableTutorials
        });
     });
  </script>
```

(you can see a working example [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete.htm))

Can you somehow take the values from the `<option>`s in the `<select>` and use them as the list for the `source: ......` ? 
 Or even transporting the vlues straight from the database to the `source`?

Comment: You can capture the option values like this `$("#clientID option").map(function(){ return $(this).val() }).get();`

Comment: You need to study mysql a bit more before you could tackle this/

Comment: yes of course you can use a database as the source, via an ajax call. It's in the documentation. No need for some weird transposition via  a select

Comment: Don't use the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky you beat me to it. Just to add - Amit , these functions are removed entirely in PHP7 due to security concerns, so eventually when you upgrade, your code will stop working entirely unless you change. You really should not be making any new code with them. I don't know where you learned that you should do it like that, but the teacher or tutorial responsible needs to update their material.